# How to parse html data using xpath in java

Tags: java, html, xpath, html-parsing

I am writing a java code where i am extracting specific data from a particular url using xpath expression.

After executing my code i am not getting the desired results.

Here is my code:

```
    try{
     URL oracle = new URL();  
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();  
InputStream is = yc.getInputStream();  
is = oracle.openStream();  
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();  
tidy.setQuiet(true);  
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);  
Document tidyDOM = tidy.parseDOM(is, null);  
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();  
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();  
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile("");  
Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(tidyDOM,XPathConstants.NODESET);  
System.out.println(result.toString());
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("error");


}
```

output:

```
       com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@7e97d1ff
```

i want product price from this url: http://www.flipkart.com/d-link-8-port-10-100m-unmanaged-standalone-switch-network/p/itmdffym2nhwyzvz

and the xpath i am usng in my code is : /html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/span

can anyone tell me what i am  doing wrong?

Comment: I can't help you with the XML parsing in Java, but your XPath expression is quite long and may become difficult to debug when/if the  source page changes. When you look at the HTML source, you'll see the prices info is inside a `<div class="prices" itemprop="offers"...`, and the final price is in various elements inside this: `<span class="fk-font-finalprice fk-font-verybig pprice fk-bold"> Rs. 530</span>`, `<meta itemprop="price" content="530"/>`. So I would recomment using something like `'.//div[@class="prices" and @itemprop="offers"]/meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content'`

Comment: @pault.   i am getting an error using this path './/div[@class="prices" and @itemprop="offers"]/meta[@itemprop="price"]/@content'

Comment: what kind of error? a syntax error? when I use `lxml.etree.XPath()` (`lxml` is a Python package, I work with Python most of the time), it looks ok, I get "530" on your page.

Comment: Naïve question but have you removed the `''` around the expression I gave? or it may have to do with the `/@content` attribute selector, that may not be compatible with `XPathConstants.NODESET`? (I simply don't do HTML parsing with Java) What's the stack trace?

Comment: @pault. yes i've removed ' ' this, getting same output i.e        com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@7e97d1ff anyway thanks for the help, i'll try something else